# Celery-Django as Daemon: Settings not found

Tags: python, django, celery, daemon

By following [this tutorial](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps), I have now a Celery-Django app that is working fine if I launch the worker with this command: 
celery -A myapp worker -n worker1.%h

in my Django settings.py, I set all parameters for Celery (IP of the messages broker, etc...). Everything is working well.

My next step now, is to run this app as a Daemon. So I have followed [this second tutorial](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html) and everything is simple, except now, my Celery parameters included in settings.py are not loaded. By example, messages broker IP is set to 127.0.0.1 but in my settings.py, I set it at an other IP address.

In the tutorial, they say:

> make sure that the module that defines your Celery app instance also sets a default value for DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE as shown in the example Django project in [First steps with Django](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps).

So I made it sure. I had in /etc/default/celeryd this:

> export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings"

Still not working... So I also, had this line in /etc/init.d/celeryd, again not working.
I don't know what to do anymore. Is someone has a clue?

EDIT:
Here is my celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('myapp')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

EDIT #2:
Here is my /etc/default/celeryd:

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1.%h"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="myapp"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ubuntu/myapp-folder/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS=""

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="ubuntu"
CELERYD_GROUP="ubuntu"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/myapp-folder
```

Comment: How does your celery.py file looks like?

Comment: You can see in my first post the celery.py.
Have you an idea?

Comment: Do you have this line [CELERYD_CHDIR="/some_dir/myapp/"]  in /etc/default/celeryd ?

Comment: It's been a few years since I tried to configure Celery. I was really hoping it had gotten better, but looks like it's the same horribleness as always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All answers here could be a part of the solution but at the end, it was still not working.
But I finally succeeded to make it work.

First of all, in `/etc/init.d/celeryd`, I have changed this line:

```
CELERYD_MULTI=${CELERYD_MULTI:-"celeryd-multi"}
```

by:

```
CELERYD_MULTI=${CELERYD_MULTI:-"celery multi"}
```

The first one was tagged as deprecated, could be the problem.

Moreover, I put this as option:
CELERYD_OPTS="--app=myapp"

And don't forget to export some environments variables:

```
# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myapp.settings"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/ubuntu/myapp-folder"
```

With all of this, it's now working on my side.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that `celeryd` can't find your Django settings file because `myapp.settings` isn't in the the `$PYTHONPATH` then the application runs.

From what I recall, Python will look in the `$PYTHONPATH` as well as the local folder when importing files. When `celeryd` runs, it likely checks the path for a module `app`, doesn't find it, then looks in the current folder for a folder `app` with an `__init__.py` (i.e. a python module).

I think that all you should need to do is add this to your `/etc/default/celeryd` file:

```
export $PYTHONPATH:path/to/your/app
```

Answer (score 1):

Below method **does not** helps to run celeryd, rather helps to run celery worker as a service which will be started at boot time.

commands like this `sudo service celery status` also works.

**celery.conf**

```
# This file sits in /etc/init
description "Celery for example"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
#Send KILL after 10 seconds
kill timeout 10

script

#project(working_ecm) and Vitrualenv(working_ecm/env) settings
chdir /home/hemanth/working_ecm
exec /home/hemanth/working_ecm/env/bin/python manage.py celery worker -B -c 2 -f /var/log/celery-ecm.log --loglevel=info >> /tmp/upstart-celery-job.log 2>&1
end script

respawn
```

Comment: Why after I do service celeryd stop, and then service celeryd status, it says that my worker is still running?

Comment: It may be a different service from a package you installed.  to confirm try renaming the /etc/init/celery.conf to /etc/init/testxyz.conf  ... and try [ sudo service testxyz start].

Answer (score 1):

In your second tutorial they set the django_settings variable to:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

This could be a reason why your settings is not found in case it changes to directory 
"/home/ubuntu/myapp-folder/"
Then you defined your app with "myapp" and then you say settings is in "myapp.settings"

This could lead to the fact that it searchs the settings file in

"/home/ubuntu/myapp-folder/myapp/myapp/settings"

So my suggestion is to remove the "myapp." in the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable and dont forget quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an answer for anyone stumbling on this more recently.

I followed the getting started First Steps guide to a tee with Celery 4.4.7, as well as the Daemonization tutorial without luck.

My initial issue:

- `celery -A app_name worker -l info` works without issue (actual celery configuration is OK).
- I could start celeryd as daemon and status command would show OK, but couldn't receive tasks. Checking logs, I saw the following:
  `[2020-11-01 09:33:15,620: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.`
- This was an indication that celeryd was not connecting to my broker (redis). Given CELERY_BROKER_URL was already set in my configuration, this meant my celery app settings were not being pulled in for the daemon process.
- I tried `sudo C_FAKEFORK=1 sh -x -l -E /etc/init.d/celeryd start` to see if *any* of my celery settings were pulled in, and i noticed that `app` was set to default `default` (not the app name specified as `CELERY_APP` in `/etc/default/celeryd`

Since `celery -A app_name worker -l info` worked, fixed the issue by exporting CELERY_APP in `/etc/default/celeryd/`, instead of just setting the variable per documentation.

TL;DR
If `celery -A app_name worker -l info` works (replace app_name with what you've defined in the Celery first steps guide), and `sudo C_FAKEFORK=1 sh -x -l -E /etc/init.d/celeryd start` does not show your celery app settings being pulled in, add the following to the end of your `/etc/default/celeryd`:

`export CELERY_APP="app_name"`